# IPython Crashes when Running Command

Tags: python, ipython, python-asyncio

I'm using `IPython 7.18.1` and `Python 3.8.3` on `Windows 10`.

When I execute a command in IPython, it returns the result of the command but with an error. Later IPython exits. This seems to happen randomly on different terminals.

```
C:\Users\14116>ipython
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.18.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: 1
Out[1]: 1

In [2]: 2
Out[2]: 2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 430, in select
    self._poll(timeout)
RuntimeError: <_overlapped.Overlapped object at 0x0000019E0480D6F0> still has pending operation at deallocation, the process may crash
In [3]:
C:\Users\14116>
```

I've searched for a long time on google, but there's no result. Any ideas?

Comment: Why use rc when the full 3.8.3 is available?

Comment: How did you install `IPython`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Download and install asyncio 3.4.3 https://pypi.org/project/asyncio/ using Command Line (CMD) or use Windows PowerShell. iPython 7.18.1 cannot work execute Command effectively if asyncio is not installed.

Remember Go to your Command Line(CMD) or Windows PowerShell and type this Command Install:

pip install asyncio

after successful install, Restart Your System.

Remember asyncio3.4.3 can only run and work on Python3.3.x or Python3.x and Above..

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and asyncio version 3.4.3 was already the version that I had installed.

For me, I had a hacky solution which was to open the `__init__.py` file in the `site-packages/IPython` directory, and add the following lines somewhere during the execution of the file:

```
import asyncio
import platform
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
   asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

The code snippet came from the solution of ["RuntimeError: <_overlapped.Overlapped object> still has pending operation at deallocation" while using aiohttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69833208/runtimeerror-overlapped-overlapped-object-still-has-pending-operation-at-de)

I'll see where I can report this bug so that it can be fixed more properly.