# Python error - self._poll(timeout) RuntimeError: <overlapped.Overlapped object at <0> still has pending operation at deallocation, process may crash

Tags: python

This error is coming without any code also. SO, if i just load ipython and it taken me to ipython prompt, then If I just press "enter" multiple times, it gives this error.

I also imported the necessary packages - import platform, asyncio if platform.system() == 'Windows': asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

And then I just load ipython and without even writing any line of code, I just press enter 2-3 times and I get this error -

(base) C:\Users\03987N744\Training_notebook>ipython -i --no-banner enumerate_vs_range.py

In [1]:

In [1]:

In [1]:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 439, in select self._poll(timeout) RuntimeError: <_overlapped.Overlapped object at 0x0000022127E19DB0> still has pending operation at deallocation, the process may crash

-- Also, this seems to be specific to **i**python and jupyter notebooks... It does not occur on python....

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and used a hacky solution which was to open the `__init__.py` file in the `site-packages/IPython` directory, and add the following lines somewhere during the execution of the file:

```
import asyncio
import platform
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
   asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

The code snippet came from the solution of ["RuntimeError: <_overlapped.Overlapped object> still has pending operation at deallocation" while using aiohttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69833208/runtimeerror-overlapped-overlapped-object-still-has-pending-operation-at-de)

I'll see where I can report this bug so that it can be fixed more properly